# sql query to return top 10 count of countries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that has '**id**' and '**country**' as it's columns (there is other stuff too, but that relevant).

In this table I have lots of incrementing id's and lots of different country names such as '**United Kingdom**', '**Hungary**' &  '**United States**'.

I'm looking for some help for a query that will return the top 10 countries and a count of them in order (descending if possible)

For example if '**Hungary**' appeared 100 times, '**United States**' 50 times and '**United Kingdom**' 25 times, then this would return:

```
'Hungary', 100
'United States', 50
'United Kingdom', 25
```

Does that make sense?

Many thanks,

Matt

Comment: does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 8):

I assume you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
Group By country
Order By COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: +1, to undo the -1. People makes mistake once in a while. Noone is perfect.

Comment: -1 - the distinct statements are incorrect (will always return "1"), and you are using "CountryName" without declaring it (I think you mean "country"?)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query :

`SELECT country_column as country, count(country_column) as c FROM COUNTRIES_TABLE group by country order by c desc limit 10;`

And then you can use `LIMIT` clause

Comment: Ah ha `SELECT country, count(country) FROM table group by country ORDER BY  count(country)  DESC LIMIT 10;` works!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT country_column as country, count(country_column) as c 
FROM COUNTRIES_TABLE 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY c DESC
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor update to Abubakkar's answer (which ignores any records with NULL country names) - if you also want to count nulls as well, update your count statement as follows:

```
SELECT Country, count(*) as countval
FROM COUNTRIES_TABLE 
Group By Country
Order By countval DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

If there were 34 nulls in the table the response will be something like:

```
'Hungary', 100
'United States', 50
NULL, 34
'United Kingdom', 25
```

I don't find the count(*) very intuitive syntax in this case but it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select top 10 Country, itemCount
From (Select country, count(*) itemCount
      From table
      Group By country) z
Order By itemCount desc
```

Comment: I think he was confused with MSSQL. Just remove `TOP 10` and put `LIMIT 10` at the end of the query.